# AngularJS ui-routing with IIS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis

I have this `AngularJS` project where I use `ui-router` for my routing.
When I run the project through a `NodeJS` server it all works fine, however I need to move it all to an `IIS` server, which have more than one application running on it.

Here's my problem: After moving the project to the `IIS` I can only load one page, whenever I try to go to one of the other pages it returns to the initial one.

This is my setup:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="SimPlannerApp">
    <head>
        <base href="/simplanner/">

        ...

        <!-- Load AngularJS modules -->
        <script src="lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Load AngularJS Application -->
        <script src="core.js"></script>

        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav ng-controller="navController">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <span class="menu">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i> <span class="hidden-xs">Menu</span>
                </span>

                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="view in nav">
                        <a href="view/{{ view.route }}">{{ view.route | capitalize }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <span class="clearfix"></span>
        </nav>

        <!-- This is where page content is inserted to -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**core.js**

```
...

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    var urlBase = '/' + config.IISProjectName;

    // For any unmatched url, redirect to '/'
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: urlBase + '/views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .state('view', {
            url: '/view/:view',
            templateUrl: urlBase + '/views/view.html',
            controller: 'viewController',
            resolve: {
                view: function ($stateParams, configService) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < config.views.length; i++) {
                        if (config.views[i].route === $stateParams.view) {
                            return config.views[i];
                        }
                    }

                    return undefined;
                }
            }
        })
        .state('404', {
            url: '{path:.*}',
            templateUrl: urlBase + '/views/404.html',
            controller: 'errorController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

...
```

Comment: Have you tried disable html5Mode?

Comment: @MrWoGu: originally I didn't have the `html5Mode` at all, I've added it in order to try and fix the problem ^^